# Unique solution of linear (inequality) system

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with $n<d$.

Under which circumstances does $Ax=a$ while $Bx\le0$ have a unique solution?

Here $A$ and $B$ are matrices.

Comment: What do you mean by $Bx\leq 0$? That every entry of $Bx$ is negative?

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes I mean that every single entry of $Bx$ is $\le0$.